# Check if X,Y column pair in table B is within delta distance of any X, Y column pair in table A

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named `origA`:

```
X, Y
10, 20
11, 2
9, 35
8, 7
```

And another one named `calcB`:

```
Xc, Yc
1, 7
9, 22
```

I want to check that for every `Xc, Yc` pair in `calcB` if there is a `X,Y`  pair in `origA` that has an euclidean distance to `Xc, Yc` that is less than `delta` and if yes, put `True` in the respective row at a new column `Detected` in `origA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wen-Ben's solution might work for small datasets. However, you run quickly into performance problems when you try to compute the distances for many points. Hence, there are already plenty of smart algorithms which reduce the amount of required distance calculations - one of them is BallTree (provided by scikit-learn):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

# Prepare the data and the search radius:
origA = pd.DataFrame()
origA['X'] = [10, 11, 9, 8]
origA['Y'] = [20, 2, 35, 7]

calcB = pd.DataFrame()
calcB['Xc'] = [1, 9]
calcB['Yc'] = [7, 22]

delta = 5

# Stack the coordinates together:
pointsA = np.column_stack([origA.X, origA.Y])
pointsB = np.column_stack([calcB.Xc, calcB.Yc])

# Create the Ball Tree and search for close points:
tree = BallTree(pointsB)
detected = tree.query_radius(pointsA, r=delta, count_only=True)

# Add results as additional column:
origA['Detected'] = detected.astype(bool)
```

**Output**

```
    X   Y   Detected
0   10  20  True
1   11  2   False
2   9   35  False
3   8   7   False
```

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer since it's indeed much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can using the method from `scipy`

```
import scipy
delta=5
ary = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(dfa, dfb, metric='euclidean')
ary
Out[189]: 
array([[15.8113883 ,  2.23606798],
       [11.18033989, 20.09975124],
       [29.12043956, 13.        ],
       [ 7.        , 15.03329638]])
dfa['detected']=(ary<delta).any(1)
dfa
Out[191]: 
    X   Y  detected
0  10  20      False
1  11   2      True
2   9  35      True
3   8   7      False
```

Comment: I can't replicate this example, my detected column gives `True` for all rows. Also, what is the meaning of `ary>20` in your code? Let's say I want the minimum distance `delta=5` to consider a source detected.

Comment: @jbssm then change the 20 to 5

Comment: No, this doesn't work, the code should be altered to `dfa['detected']=(ary<5).any(1)`. In any case, thank you, you pointed me to the right direction. Please change the code so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: I made the edit myself, it must be `any(1)` instead of the `any()`